# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to insert the answer to a user's security question, for use in the pin reset feature.

Ellucian banner v8+ provides an API for running this and I very new to their API and from the looks of the error message below, I am far from running this correctly. Any help is appreciated.

I tried running this in Oracle SQL Developer:

```
execute gb_pin_answer.p_create(
    P_PIDM        =>    12345,
    P_NUM         =>    1,
    p_gobqstn_id  =>    1,
    p_qstn_desc   =>    '',
    p_ansr_desc   =>    'David',
    p_ansr_salt   =>    'A123B456',
    p_user_id     =>    'W:H12345678',
    p_data_origin =>    'WWW_USER',
    p_rowid_out         OUT gb_common.internal_record_id_type
);
```

This is a shot in the dark, but I thought I'd give it a shot, error message that displays when trying to execute that package's p_create function:

> Error starting at line 15 in command: execute gb_pin_answer.p_create(
>   Error report: ORA-06550: line 1, column 30: PLS-00103: Encountered the
>   symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:
>
> ( ) - + case mod new not null          table continue avg count
>   current exists max min prior sql    stddev sum variance execute
>   multiset the both leading    trailing forall merge year month day hour
>   minute second    timezone_hour timezone_minute timezone_region
>   timezone_abbr    time timestamp interval date    
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:
>
> Error starting at line 16 in command: P_PIDM              =>  12345, Error
>   report: Unknown Command
>
> Error starting at line 17 in command: P_NUM                   =>  1, Error report:
>   Unknown Command
>
> Error starting at line 18 in command: p_gobqstn_id    =>  1, Error report:
>   Unknown Command
>
> Error starting at line 19 in command: p_qstn_desc     =>  '', Error
>   report: Unknown Command
>
> Error starting at line 20 in command: p_ansr_desc   =>    'David', Error
>   report: Unknown Command
>
> Error starting at line 21 in command: p_ansr_salt   => 'A123B456',
>   Error report: Unknown Command
>
> Error starting at line 22 in command: p_user_id     => 'W:H12345678',
>   Error report: Unknown Command
>
> Error starting at line 23 in command: p_data_origin => 'WWW_USER',
>   Error report: Unknown Command
>
> Error starting at line 24 in command: p_rowid_out   OUT
>   gb_common.internal_record_id_type Error report: Unknown Command
>
> Error starting at line 25 in command: ) Error report: Unknown Command

This is where I read up on using this function, p_create: http://inb1.banner.ecu.edu:9090/api_erd_index_guide/api/general/gb_pin_answer.html#p_create

UPDATE: code that is erroring out:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
declare
  l_rowid_out gb_common.internal_record_id_type;
BEGIN
  gb_pin_answer.p_create(P_PIDM => 36706, P_NUM => 1, P_GOBQSTN_ID => 1, P_QSTN_DESC => '', P_ANSR_DESC => 'David', P_ANSR_SALT => 'HB123456', P_USER_ID => 'H00036657', P_DATA_ORIGIN => 'WWW_USER', P_ROWID_OUT => 1_rowid_out);
  dbms_output.put_line('rowid: ' || l_rowid_out);
END;
```

Error msg:

> Error report: ORA-06550: line 4, column 199: PLS-00363: expression '1'
>   cannot be used as an assignment target ORA-06550: line 4, column 3:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the `execute`. That's actually shorthand for a short anonymous PL/SQL block, and cannot be split across lines. (Except maybe with a continuation character, but I can't remember off-hand if I've ever got that to work). Only the first line is translated, so it's effectively trying to run:

```
begin execute gb_pin_answer.p_create(; end;
/
```

... and it quite reasonably then doesn't like the command ending as `p_create(;`. The rest of the procedure call is then treated as 10 separate commands, which generate the other errors you get, and they are also reasonable in that context.

The solution is to either put the entire procedure call on one line, which will make it harder to read; or simply to use your own block, rather than relying on `execute`:

```
begin
    gb_pin_answer.p_create(
        ...
    );
end;
/
```

The last parameter isn't right though; the bit from `OUT ...` needs to be replaced with `=> some_value`, like you've done with the others. But it is an out parameter, so you need something to put the value in. Without seeing what else is in the script you're running I can't tell if you've already taken care of it, but with this pattern you can probably just add a variable to the anonymous block:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
    l_rowid_out gb_common.internal_record_id_type;
begin
    gb_pin_answer.p_create(
        ...
        p_rowid_out => l_rowid_out
    );
    -- optional
    dbms_output.put_line('rowid: ' || l_rowid_out);
end;
/
```

Comment: I tried:

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
declare
  l_rowid_out gb_common.internal_record_id_type;
BEGIN
  gb_pin_answer.p_create(P_PIDM => 36706, P_NUM => 1, P_GOBQSTN_ID => 1, P_QSTN_DESC => '', P_ANSR_DESC => 'David', P_ANSR_SALT => 'HB123456', P_USER_ID => 'H00036657', P_DATA_ORIGIN => 'WWW_USER', P_ROWID_OUT => 1_rowid_out);
  dbms_output.put_line('rowid: ' || l_rowid_out);
END;
/

Comment: Snippet of error message it returned: 

Error report:
ORA-06550: line 4, column 215:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "_" when expecting one of the following:

   ) , * & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
The symbol ", was inserted before "_" to continue.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: @Brad - did you really have `1_rowid_out` instead of `l_rowid_out` as the parameter?

Comment: Yes, I am not sure what value needs to be passed. I am brand new to these packages.

Comment: @Brad your comments would be easier to read if you surrounded the code and error parts with backticks, incidentally... though they're really too long for comments anyway... I'll see if I can recreate that. But `1_rowid_out` is wrong, it has to match the variable you declared. If the error report actually says `... the symbol "_" when ...` then that is the problem; just change `1_` to `l_`.

Comment: I updated my original question with the code formatted properly.

Comment: That worked! Now to get this to work in a sql call to use in a php application I am writing for users to set their security question.

Comment: @Brad - can't help you with PHP, but I would imagine it will let you execute a PL/SQL block like this. Make sure you use bind variables to avoid SQL injection. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Alex, you have helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

From the last edit, I see that you misstaken `1` for `l`...
`1_rowid_out` instead of `l_rowid_out`.

You cannot start a variable with a number like you tried to.

Answer (score 0):

We got this error when mixing Dapper and native Oracle MDA constructs. Specifically trying to use the WithConnection construct with native Oracle driver. It didn't like that and returned a very similar and nonsensical error message "ORA-06550: line 1, column 259: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol...blah blah blah"