# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ON" when expecting one of the following

Tags: oracle, plsql, compiler-errors

**Please note:** I have tried other Stack overflow questions, but none solve my problem...

I am getting this error: `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ON" when expecting one of the following` with the following code:

---

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
    v_province         VARCHAR(4) := &province;
    v_numberOfVisits   NUMBER;
    v_totallaborcost   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    findvisitsandlaborcost(v_numberofvisits, v_totallaborcost, v_province);
    dbms_output.put_line('Number of visits for province '
                         || v_province
                         || ': '
                         || v_numberofvisits);
    dbms_output.put_line('Total labor cost for province '
                         || v_province
                         || ': '
                         || v_totallaborcost);
END;
/
```

---

findvisitsandlaborcost definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE findvisitsandlaborcost (
    numberofvisits   OUT   NUMBER,
    totallaborcost   OUT   NUMBER,
    province         VARCHAR
) AS
    v_numberofvisits   si.servinv.servinvno%TYPE;
    v_totallaborcost   si.servinv.laborcost%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT
        COUNT(servinvno) AS "Number of Visits",
        SUM(laborcost) AS "Total labor cost"
    INTO
        v_numberofvisits,
        v_totallaborcost
    FROM
        si.servinv si
    WHERE
        si.custname IN (
            SELECT
                custname
            FROM
                si.customer
            WHERE
                custprovince = province
        );

    numberofvisits := v_numberofvisits;
    totallaborcost := v_totallaborcost;
END;
/
```

---

**What I've tried**

These are some links that I have tried to solve my problem with but none worked:

- [PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308701/pls-00103-encountered-the-symbol-when-expecting-one-of-the-following)
- https://kb.informatica.com/solution/3/Pages/14954.aspx
- https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/2785
- https://it.toolbox.com/question/pls-00103-encountered-the-symbol-when-expecting-one-of-the-following-070710
- https://logic.edchen.org/how-to-resolve-pls-00103-encountered-the-symbol-when-expecting-one-of-the/

Comment: The only 'ON' I can see is in the line `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;` . This is a command that only SQLPLUS or similar will understand. If you are running this code over something like JDBC or .Net then it wont make sense. Try without the `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;` and see if that helps. If not, please provide details of which tool/language you are running this in.

Comment: @TenG No, it's still the same error. My environment recognizes `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON`. I am using SQL developer by the way with Oracle.

Comment: You have this substitution variable ` &province ` . Exactly what do you enter for this value? remember, what you enter is exactly what the ` &province` gets replaced with, so if you are adding a string value you must include single quotes.

Comment: @TenG Yeah, that fixed it! I had it without single quotes and I changed it to have single quotes. Now there is another, new error in my procedure. Thanks!

Comment: @TenG Please place your answer to my question and I will give you the correct answer...

Comment: What tells the new error ?

Comment: Please don't forget to mark the correct answer as such.

Comment: In the function, you declare two variables using the `%TYPE` attribute. But you assign to them the values returned by `COUNT()` and `SUM()` from an aggregate query, and then you use them to assign values to `OUT` arguments of `number` data type. So, why use the `%TYPE` attribute when you declare them? That doesn't make sense; it may lead to errors, if `SERVINVO`, in particular, is not of data type `number` (but, for example, of some character data type) - since the function variable that corresponds to it will store the `COUNT()`, which is always a `number`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error was caused by this line:

`v_province         VARCHAR(4) := &province;`

When this is run, the substitution variable is replaced exactly with the is keyed in as teh input.

Seeing as the variable is of type VARCHAR, if the value being entered is a string, it must be entered with the single quote, e.g. `'abcd'`. If you just eneter `abcd`, i.e without the single quotes you will get an error.

An neater way to do this is to code this as follows:

`v_province         VARCHAR(4) := '&province';`

Now, you can enter the as `abcd` without the quotes and it will work.

Comment: And, to clarify to the last detail: very likely the OP entered the input `ON` (for the Canadian province Ontario, or perhaps a province in another country with the same province code). The execution engine then saw `v_province varchar(4) := ON` with the RHS looking like a variable name or a language keyword, as it is not quoted - and coughed, since the token `ON` doesn't make sense in that context.